# Any advice to load Async Image in SwiftUI that is outside of List View?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and Swift UI development, trying to learn and would consider myself a beginner to programming as a whole. So any advice to help me improve is welcome, thank you!

I'm trying to build a feed of news posts (that I'm pulling from a public API).

Looping through the JSON, the list is built out along with the Async Images.

While scrolling through the list, I realise that images only load on view. Any kind soul to guide me to improve my code, which the expected output is the images loads when the List loads.

I'm tried to Google for solution but couldn't find anything remotely close to the issue/challenge here.

**FeedView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeedView: View {
    
    @State private var feed: Feed?
    let sortFeedBy: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<(feed?.posts.count ?? 1), id: \.self) { index in
                    ZStack {
                        ZStack {
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                    .frame(height: 4)
                                
                                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                                    if feed?.posts[index].type == "text" {
                                        ZStack{
                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14.0)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray5))
                                            Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
                                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray3))
                                        }
                                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                    } else if feed?.posts[index].type == "link" {
                                        ZStack{
                                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: prependDomaintoDirectory(directory: feed?.posts[index].link?.image?.url ?? ""))) { image in
                                                image
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .scaledToFill()
                                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                                    .cornerRadius(12.0)
                                                    .clipped()
                                            } placeholder: {
                                                ZStack{
                                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14.0)
                                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray5))
                                                    Image(systemName: "safari")
                                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray3))
                                                }
                                                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14.0)
                                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray5))
                                    }
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                        .frame(width: 12)
                                    
                                    VStack {
                                        HStack {
                                            Text(feed?.posts[index].title ?? "")
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                        
                                        HStack {
                                            Text(feed?.posts[index].communityName ?? "").bold()
                                            Text(feed?.posts[index].link?.url.showDomainOnly ?? "")
                                                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                        
                                        Spacer()
                                            .frame(height: 20)
                                        
                                        HStack {
                                            PostStatsActionButtonView(value: Double(feed?.posts[index].upvotes ?? 0), symbol: "arrow.up.circle", type: "\(PostStatsType.number)")
                                            PostStatsActionButtonView(value: Double(feed?.posts[index].noComments ?? 0), symbol: "bubble.middle.bottom", type: "\(PostStatsType.number)")
                                            PostStatsActionButtonView(value: 3, symbol: "clock", type: "\(PostStatsType.time)")
                                            Spacer()
                                            PostStatsActionButtonView(value: 0, symbol: "ellipsis", type: "\(PostStatsType.null)").font(.title3)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                
                                Spacer()
                                    .frame(height: 4)
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: PostView(postId: feed?.posts[index].publicId ?? "000")) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                            .opacity(0.0)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                // if sortfeedby = flame
                Button {
                    print("x")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "flame")
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            do {
                feed = try await fetchFeed(sort: "\(sortFeedBy)")
            } catch Error.invalidURL {
                print("Invalid Endpoint URL (Feed)")
            } catch Error.invalidResponse {
                print("Invalid Response (Feed)")
            } catch Error.invalidData {
                print("Invalid Data (Feed)")
            } catch {
                print("Unexpected Error (Feed Data)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FetchFeed Func**

```
func fetchFeed(sort: String) async throws -> Feed {
    let endpoint = "https://discuit.net/api/posts?sort=\(sort)"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else { throw Error.invalidURL }
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
        throw Error.invalidResponse
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys
        return try decoder.decode(Feed.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        throw Error.invalidData
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? try to express it as "the code is doing X and I need it to do Y"